# R Returning Unexpected NA after using strptime

Tags: r

When I enter

```
strptime("01/04/2011 11:11:19 AM", "%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S %p", tz = "")
```

into R, it returns NA. I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%y`should be changed to `%Y` and specify the `format`

```
strptime("01/04/2011 11:11:19 AM", format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", tz = "")
#[1] "2011-01-04 11:11:19 IST"
```

Comment: Ahhh, i needed the %Y, not %y. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

%y  is 2-digit year [0-99].
but you need 4 digit year so you need to enter %Y
so it should be like `strptime("01/04/2011 11:11:19 AM", format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", tz = "")`